# Sync timezone, both MySql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my web app (developed it with **Codeigniter** last version), I'm using `timestamp` and `datetime` field in MySql db tables.

For `datetime` filling, I use php `date` function. I've set `date_default_timezone_set` in `index.php` and everything is well on local.

Now I move app on live server and on testing, see the timestamp (on insert a row in db) is different from `date_default_timezone_set`!!!

I search a lot and see other's guide, but nothing happened!

`$this->db->query('SET time_zone = ""');,

add `date_default_timezone_set`,

change `$config['time_reference']` in config file,

create a parent model and set time zone in that or...

none of them did not worked for me!

How could solve this which will be correct and practical? A way that **set it in one place, like php**, that is set in index.php. Could you guide me to handle this issue?

thanks.